# How do I forcefully unload a ByteArray from memory in ActionScript 3?

Tags: actionscript-3

I have tried so much without success:

```
byteArray.length = 0;
byteArray = new ByteArray();
```

And also

```
for ( var i:int=0; i < byteArray.length; i++ ) {
    byteArray[i] = null;
}
```

Comment: You have no direct memory access in AS3. AS3 Virtual Machine (AVM) does it behind the curtains. However, you can **suggest** it is time for Garbage Collector (GC) to do its job. **System.gc()** is available in **AIR** and **Debugging** runtimes, it forces AVM to free all the memory that is garbage (your first piece of code turns the ByteArray content into garbage, yes). The **Flash Plugin** runtime provides 
**System.pauseForGCIfCollectionImminent(...)**. It does not force GC to do the job, but makes a **push**, the lower the argument you pass - the more likely GC will be invoked.

Comment: ByteArray's have a `clear()` method that free's up the memory used by the ByteArray's content.    http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/utils/ByteArray.html#clear()

Comment: @BadFeelingAboutThis Good one. Live and learn, me : )))

Comment: Actually byteArray = null should let the garbage collector do the job on its next run ? Note that the garbage collector does not kicks in immediately but might free up the memory several seconds later